# Create and Append new divs on button click with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

```js
//hide element
function hide(x) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
    elems[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

//show element
function show(x) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
    elems[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}

/* *************** listWrapper *************** */

var boardContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('board-container');
var newList = document.createElement('div'); //create new list-wrapper for holding lists
newList.className = 'new-list'; //assign id or class to div
newList.classList.add("list-wrapper"); //add another classname to the new-list div

//Check to see if a board-container exists and creates it if it does not exist and appends it to its parentNode
var boardContainerExist = true;
if (boardContainer === null) {
  boardContainer = document.createElement('div');
  boardContainer.class = 'board-container';
  // adds the newly created element to the DOM
  boardContainerExist = false;
}
for (var i = 0; i < boardContainer.length; i++) {
  document.body.appendChild(newList); //add list-wrapper to the body/ or to the DOM
  // document.getElementsByClassName("new-list") += "list-wrapper";
  boardContainer[i].insertBefore(newList, boardContainer[i].childNodes[0]); //append new-list before the first-child
  // document.getElementsByClassName('board-container')[0].appendChild(newList);
}
//create list-container
var listContainer = document.createElement('div');
listContainer.className = 'list-container';

//create list-head-container
var listHeadContainer = document.createElement('div');
listHeadContainer.className = 'list-head-container';

//create div to hold textarea
var textareaContainer = document.createElement('div');
textareaContainer.className = 'textarea-container';


//create textarea for lists
var textareaElement = document.createElement('textarea');
textareaElement.setAttribute("type", "text");
textareaElement.setAttribute("class", "textarea-title");
textareaElement.setAttribute("overflow", "break-word");
textareaElement.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter list title...");


//create div container for ellipsis 
//Note: The icon with three dots is called an ellipsis
var ellipsisContainer = document.createElement('div');
ellipsisContainer.className = 'ellipsis-container';

// create list to hold ellipsis
var ellipsisLink = document.createElement('a');
ellipsisLink.className = 'ellipsisLink';
ellipsisLink.setAttribute('href', '#');
ellipsisLink.innerHTML = '...';

//Add inner elements
newList.appendChild(listContainer); //add list-container inside new-list
listContainer.appendChild(listHeadContainer); //add list-head-container inside list-container
listHeadContainer.appendChild(textareaContainer); //add textarea container inside list-head-holder
textareaContainer.appendChild(textareaElement); //add textarea container inside textarea-container
textareaContainer.appendChild(ellipsisContainer); //add ellipsis container inside textarea-container
ellipsisContainer.appendChild(ellipsisLink); //add ellipsis link inside ellipsis container

var titleTaker = document.getElementsByClassName('list-input').value;
textareaElement.innerHTML = titleTaker;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(12, 57, 83);
}


/* *************** boardWrapper *************** */

.board-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  /* flex-grow: 1;  */
  font-size: 14px;
}

.board-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.list-wrapper.first-wrapper {
  width: 280px;
  background-color: rgb(237, 239, 240);
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*** for rounded corners ***/
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.list-wrapper {
  width: 280px;
  background-color: rgb(237, 239, 240);
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*** for rounded corners ***/
}

div.list-wrapper:first-child {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.list-content {
  height: 900px;
}

.list-content {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 280px;
}

form {
  /* padding: 5px; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

a.list-links {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

a.list-links:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

span.add-another-list {
  display: none;
}

.fa-plus {
  font-size: 14px;
}

span.link-selector {
  padding: 10px;
  /* background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); */
}

.add-list-button-container {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

input[type=text].list-input {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgb(127, 170, 199);
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(127, 170, 199);
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.add-list-button-container {
  margin: 0 5px 5px;
  display: none;
}

input[type=submit].list-input-button {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: #5aac44;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #3f6f21;
  background-color: rgb(90, 172, 68);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgb(46, 73, 39);
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.fa-times {
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.textarea-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgb(127, 170, 199);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  /* Removes the blue glow from around textarea */
  resize: none;
  /* Removes resize handle */
}

.textarea-title {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(127, 170, 199);
  height: 20px;
  max-height: 120px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  /* clear: right !important; */
}

.ellipsis-container {
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 47px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.ellipsis-container:hover {
  background-color: rgba(214, 218, 220, 0.8);
}

.ellipsis-container a.ellipsisLink {
  font-size: 21px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  /* width: 16px; */
  line-height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie-edge">

  <title></title>

  <!-- Link to CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- Link to Font-Awesome 5 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--Link to google fonts - Roboto and Open sans (400, 400 italics, 700 bold, 700 italics)-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- *************** boardWrapper *************** -->
  <div class="board-wrapper">
    <div class="board-container">
      <!-- New lists are being created dynamically via javascript and are being placed here -->
      <div class="list-wrapper first-wrapper">
        <form onsubmit="return show('list-wrapper');">
          <a class="list-links" href="#" onclick="hide('list-links'); show('list-input'); show('add-list-button-container'); ">
            <span class="link-selector">
              <span class="plus-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
            <span class="add-list">Add list</span>
            <span class="add-another-list">Add another list</span>
            </span>
          </a>
          <input type="text" class="list-input" required minlength="1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="500" placeholder="Enter list title...">
          <div class="add-list-button-container">
            <input class="list-input-button" type="submit" value="Add List" required minlength="1" maxlength="500" placeholder="Enter list title...">
            <a class="list-close-button" href="#"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
          </div>
        </form>
        <!-- end of form -->
        <!-- list content -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of list-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of board-container -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of board-wrapper -->
  <!-- Link to JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

ther answers but none really covers all my issues.

So here's what I want to do

I'm working on a project to clone Trello using only HTML, CSS and vanilla JavaScript. I'm fairly new to javaScript and I'm trying to create multiple lists and I started by creating dynamic lists.

***Here's what should happen:***

  1. A new list (which is really a div with a textarea) should be added (to the left side of the screen) each time the user writes text into the input field and clicks on the ***Add a list*** button.
   2. The input that the user adds should be transferred over to new list as a title heading for that list. This title should be editable (meaning the user should be able to change the title text whenever he/she wants to.

***Here are the issues I'm having:***

  1. The current code only allows me to add one single list.

  2. I'm also not able to transfer text from the input field to the new list (in the textarea) --- what is now being transferred is the word 'undefined'.

  3. Also, the list and buttons disappear after it has been clicked

It was suggested that I use unique IDs for the list but I just don't know how to do that as yet.

Link to the code on Codepen: https://codepen.io/Joanc/pen/MZjJvy

Really appreciate and looking forward to your help

```js
//hide element
function hide(x) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
    elems[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

//show element
function show(x) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
    elems[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}

/* *************** listWrapper *************** */

var boardContainer = document.getElementById('board-container');
var newList = document.createElement('div'); //create new list-wrapper for holding lists
newList.className = 'new-list'; //assign id or class to div
newList.classList.add("list-wrapper"); //add another classname to the new-list div

document.body.appendChild(newList); //add list-wrapper to the body/ or to the DOM
var boardContainer = document.getElementById('board-container');
boardContainer.insertBefore(newList, boardContainer.childNodes[0]); //append new-list before the first-child
// 
//create list-container
var listContainer = document.createElement('div');
listContainer.className = 'list-container';

//create list-head-container
var listHeadContainer = document.createElement('div');
listHeadContainer.className = 'list-head-container';

//create div to hold textarea
var textareaContainer = document.createElement('div');
textareaContainer.className = 'textarea-container';


//create textarea for lists
var textareaElement = document.createElement('textarea');
textareaElement.setAttribute("type", "text");
textareaElement.setAttribute("class", "textarea-title");
textareaElement.setAttribute("overflow", "break-word");
textareaElement.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter list title...");


//create div container for ellipsis 
//Note: The icon with three dots is called an ellipsis
var ellipsisContainer = document.createElement('div');
ellipsisContainer.className = 'ellipsis-container';

// create list to hold ellipsis
var ellipsisLink = document.createElement('a');
ellipsisLink.className = 'ellipsisLink';
ellipsisLink.setAttribute('href', '#');
ellipsisLink.innerHTML = '...';

//Add inner elements
newList.appendChild(listContainer); //add list-container inside new-list
listContainer.appendChild(listHeadContainer); //add list-head-container inside list-container
listHeadContainer.appendChild(textareaContainer); //add textarea container inside list-head-holder
textareaContainer.appendChild(textareaElement); //add textarea container inside textarea-container
textareaContainer.appendChild(ellipsisContainer); //add ellipsis container inside textarea-container
ellipsisContainer.appendChild(ellipsisLink); //add ellipsis link inside ellipsis container

//grabbing user input and assigning it to title textarea
var titleTaker = document.getElementsByClassName('list-input').value;
textareaElement.innerHTML = titleTaker;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(12, 57, 83);
}


/* *************** boardWrapper *************** */

.board-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  /* flex-grow: 1;  */
  font-size: 14px;
}

#board-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.list-wrapper.first-wrapper {
  width: 280px;
  background-color: rgb(237, 239, 240);
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*** for rounded corners ***/
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.list-wrapper {
  width: 280px;
  background-color: rgb(237, 239, 240);
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*** for rounded corners ***/
}

div.list-wrapper:first-child {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.list-content {
  height: 900px;
}

#board-container {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.list-content {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 280px;
}

form {
  /* padding: 5px; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

a.list-links {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

a.list-links:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

span.add-another-list {
  display: none;
}

.fa-plus {
  font-size: 14px;
}

span.link-selector {
  padding: 10px;
  /* background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); */
}

.add-list-button-container {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

input[type=text].list-input {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgb(127, 170, 199);
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(127, 170, 199);
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.add-list-button-container {
  margin: 0 5px 5px;
  display: none;
}

input[type=submit].list-input-button {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: #5aac44;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #3f6f21;
  background-color: rgb(90, 172, 68);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgb(46, 73, 39);
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.fa-times {
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.textarea-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgb(127, 170, 199);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  /* Removes the blue glow from around textarea */
  resize: none;
  /* Removes resize handle */
}

.textarea-title {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(127, 170, 199);
  height: 20px;
  max-height: 120px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  /* clear: right !important; */
}

.ellipsis-container {
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 47px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.ellipsis-container:hover {
  background-color: rgba(214, 218, 220, 0.8);
}

.ellipsis-container a.ellipsisLink {
  font-size: 21px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  /* width: 16px; */
  line-height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie-edge">

  <title></title>

  <!-- Link to CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- Link to Font-Awesome 5 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--Link to google fonts - Roboto and Open sans (400, 400 italics, 700 bold, 700 italics)-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- *************** boardWrapper *************** -->
  <div class="board-wrapper">
    <div id="board-container">
      <div class="list-wrapper first-wrapper">
        <form onsubmit="return show('list-wrapper');">
          <a class="list-links" href="#" onclick="hide('list-links'); show('list-input'); show('add-list-button-container'); ">
            <span class="link-selector">
              <span class="plus-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
            <span class="add-list">Add list</span>
            <span class="add-another-list">Add another list</span>
            </span>
          </a>
          <input type="text" class="list-input" required minlength="1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="500" placeholder="Enter list title...">
          <div class="add-list-button-container">
            <input class="list-input-button" type="submit" value="Add List" required minlength="1" maxlength="500" placeholder="Enter list title...">
            <a class="list-close-button" href="#"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
          </div>
        </form>
        <!-- end of form -->
        <!-- list content -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of list-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of board-container -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of board-wrapper -->
  <!-- Link to JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, @joan this has a number of issue. But most obvious is there is no function to 'create' new boards. Only calls that run once in the page. There is a lot of work to tidy this one up.

Comment: @PaulThomas Thanks. I added updated the code to add a check to see if board-container is present and to create it if it's not.  Is that what you were referring to? and what else can  I'm kind of just learning JavaScript so I would appreciate any more help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Joan, because the javascript needed to be changed substantially I have created a simpler version of the code you are working on. With comments to call out how the functions would work. I hope it helps though.

```js
// This method creates a single work item on the board and assigns click methods.
var createNewWorkItem = function(itemContainer) {
  if(itemContainer && (typeof itemContainer.appendChild !== undefined)) {

    var workItemActionPanel = document.createElement('div');
    workItemActionPanel.setAttribute('class', 'work-item-panel' );
    workItemActionPanel.onclick = closeWorkItemActionPanel;
    
    var workItem = document.createElement('div');
    workItem.setAttribute( 'class', 'work-item' );
    workItem.onclick = showWorkItemActionPanel;
    
    workItem.appendChild(workItemActionPanel);
    itemContainer.appendChild(workItem);    
  }
};

// This is called when user clicks the action panel, closes it and calls to create
// a new work item
var closeWorkItemActionPanel = function(e) {
  e.currentTarget.style.display = 'none';
  var board = document.getElementById("workBoard");
  createNewWorkItem(board);
  e.stopPropagation() ;
};

// This is called when user clicks on a work item and shows the action panel
var showWorkItemActionPanel = function(e) {
  var actionPanel = e.currentTarget.childNodes[0];
  if(actionPanel.className !== 'work-item-panel') {
    e.currentTarget.childNodes.forEach(node => {
      if(node.className == 'work-item-panel') actionPanel = node;
    });
  }

  actionPanel.style.display = 'inline-block';
};

// Initialize when the document has loaded.
(function(){
  var board = document.getElementById("workBoard");
  createNewWorkItem(board);

})();
```

```css
.work-board {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.work-item {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.work-item-panel {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
    <div id="workBoard" class="work-board">


    </div>
```

I am using repl to write this, you can fork and play here: https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/PTSimpleWorkBoardSample

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I really appreciate it.  I have noticed a functionality issue in your code and would love to hear how I can revise it.  I notice that a new div (work-item) is created whenever I click on any one of the divs.  That's not exactly how I want it to function

Comment: What should actually happen is that the only time a new div is created is when I click on the first div.  The first div (contains a form which has an input field and a submit button in it and when this button is clicked it should have the power to create a new single div on every click.  any other div.  Basically, when a user clicks on a button inside the first div, a new div (work-item) is to be created. So the first div should function differently from the other newly created divs.

Comment: Ok, I understand. You could add a flag parameter to the create function that allows you to toggle creation. Note it was intended to demonstrate the need for functions to create your divs.

Comment: Yes I understand there is a need for functions, the problem is that I'm new to javascript and I don't understand when or even to create them very well. I'm not even sure I understand what you mean by flag parameter to toggle creation. Just for clarification and sorry if this should be obvious but could you explain a little more about what the closeWorkItemActionPanel and showWorkItemActionPanel functions are doing? Thanks

Comment: No problem, what languages are you familiar with? I will try and help from there.

Comment: None... I used to use C# but that was a while back and even then I only learnt the basics.

Comment: Ok, javascript can appear very 'friendly'. But much like English it is easy to do a little and almost impossible to master. If you are really looking to learn, I highly recommend some of the great online learning that is available. First things to learn with the web are page life cycle and how the DOM is structured. From there look at Javascript encapsulation techniques. I am sorry this sounds very heavy, but as you look to do more you will need these concepts. https://developer.mozilla.org is a good reference resource and www.pluralsight.com is a great paid online training repository.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations.  I have taken some tutorials but I know I have a long way to go.  I just wanted to jump in and start coding while learning.  This trello clone is a project I'm doing with a group and as you can guess, I'm in charge of creating new lists so I really want to complete this but I understand if you can't help me any further.  thanks for your assistance thus far.

Comment: My advice is don't rush, your HTML is clearly good. Take a step back and learn JavaScript properly. It is worth the effort. Very powerful. I will help. What do you want fixed.

Comment: Thanks so much. Will do.  I'm currently working on refactoring the code using your answer.  I will update you as soon as I'm done doing that ok.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a plan !